# How to resolve a type in global.asax with Unity.AspNet.WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, webactivator

I've got Unity.AspNet.WebApi through NuGet into my Asp.Net WebApi application and all my controllers are able to resolve classes through constructor injection. Easy and simple.

However I am not sure on how to resolve classes in global.asax as I don't have direct access to UnityContainer here. I've tried below and it seems to be working. Is there a better way?

Also, as this is start up code not sure if this clashes with the WebActivator which registers UnityContainer. I am concerned that whether there woould be always a Dependencyresolver ready in Application_Start() method.

```
var o = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IService));
var service = (IService)o;
serviceInitializePermissionsCache();
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

```
var service = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<IService>();
```